# Call and Run Function after Inserting HTML with jQuery and replaceWith

Tags: jquery, html, dom, replacewith

I have a jQuery replaceWith that loads a few image links into the html.
I'm trying to (re)aplly the cycle plugin on these images so they form a gallery.
I played around with  .live but nothing seems to respond.

What is obvious wrong here (apart that there are much better ways than using rplaceWith)
My guess is that i have to call the function slideshow after the replaceWith, even though other posts say this should work fine...

```
$("#studiesB").live('click', function(slideShow){
 $(".content").replaceWith('<img src=images/1.jpg> <img src=images/2.jpg>');

});

$(function slideShow() {

    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:      'fade',
        timeout:  0,
        prev:    '#prev',
        next:    '#next',


        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
    });

    function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
        var s = idx > 2 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
        return '<li'+s+'><a href="#">'+(idx+1)+'</a></li>';
    };

});
```

Comment: Have you left code out of your example? Why do you have a "slideShow" parameter in the function you created in your click event when it doesn't seem to be used? Without seeing more code, Id guess the issues lies with the fact that once the plugin is called, that it words based on the content of the object passed it it and simply using replaceWith is manipulating the DOM after the fact.

Comment: I was afraid of that, i would like too apply the function slideShow onto the images after the dom is manipulated or in normal language: click button to replace .content with <img src=images/1.jpg> <img src=images/2.jpg> and then apply function slideshow onto it.

Answer (score 0):

put your .live function inside $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#studiesB").live('click', function(slideShow){
      $(".content").replaceWith('<img src=images/1.jpg> <img src=images/2.jpg>');
    });
});
```

anything that written to run at the beginning of the script should be wrapped inside a function that will be execute when the document element triggers the ready event

otherwise it won't work